# Possible to render .vue single file components without transpiling?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, transpiler

Can .vue files somehow be executed without transpiling them?

Similar to how .less files can be used directly, by just including the less.js compiler. Basically the less.js will compile the less in memory to css, then inject the css in the page.

Does Vue have something like that, a runtime compiler or something?

Comment: but it seems X/ Y problen

Comment: why x y problem? I just want to avoid GBs of build tools and processes running in the background. Could you share how to compile on the fly with Vue?

Comment: @Alex Basically it's `@vue/compiler-sfc`. You can check how it works in https://github.com/vuejs/repl and https://play.vuejs.org/ . It looks like XY because you didn't originally explain the motivation, while what you're asking may not be common or practical. This "I just want to avoid GBs of build tools" sounds exactly like this, devs use computationally expensive tools like vite not because they must spend ram on something but because this allows to focus on writing production code instead of reinventing a wheel

Comment: You may want to check https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue3-sfc-loader in case your goal is to use sfcs without a build tool (the question doesn't clearly state this). This is third-party tool that works in undetermined ways and may cause problems you wouldn't have when using officially recommended workflows. And it does transpilation. You probably meant that you want to avoid bundlers like vite